# Resizing uploaded image in Laravel and store in S3 is not working

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I am trying to upload a couple of resized images to S3, but somehow all images have the same size. Storing them locally in different sizes gives no problems. What am I missing?

```
public function uploadFileToS3(Request $request) {
    $image = Image::make($request->file('image'))->encode('jpg', 75);
    $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');

    $image_file_name = $this->generateName($request->name) . '.jpg';
    $file_path = '/' . config('folder') . '/' . $request->name . '/';

    $s3->put($file_path.'original_'.$image_file_name, $image, 'public');
    $s3->put($file_path.'medium_'.$image_file_name, $image->fit(300, 300), 'public');
    $s3->put($file_path.'thumb_'.$image_file_name, $image->fit(100, 100), 'public');

    return json_encode(array(
        'filename' => $image_file_name
    ));
}
```

All versions are stored successfully in S3, only all in the same size

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have two possible solutions.

Try to do the image manipulation completely before attempting to store them:

```
$s3->put($file_path.'original_'.$image_file_name, $image, 'public');
$image->fit(300, 300);
$s3->put($file_path.'medium_'.$image_file_name, $image, 'public');
$image->fit(100, 100);
$s3->put($file_path.'thumb_'.$image_file_name, $image, 'public');
```

---

Try to cast the image to a string, the actual output file contents should work fine:

```
$s3->put($file_path.'original_'.$image_file_name, (string) $image, 'public');
```

Answer (score 0):

... Well I managed to fix this by first storing the resized image to a local tmp folder and then uploading it. It's a work around that I really do not like a lot, cause in my opinion it's too much coding for something that should be dealt with within Laravel.

```
    $folder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/tmp/';
    $image_file_name = $this->generateName($request->name) . '.jpg';

    // save original
    $image->save($folder . 'original_' . $image_file_name);
    $s3->put($file_path.'original_'.$image_file_name, fopen($folder.'original_'.$image_file_name, 'r+'), 'public');

    // generate thumb
    $image = $image->fit(100, 100);
    $image->save($folder . 'thumb_' . $image_file_name);
    $s3->put($file_path.'thumb_'.$image_file_name, fopen($folder.'thumb_'.$image_file_name, 'r+'), 'public');
```